# C#, Creating an Array in an Object Class and executing the method, custom sorting method

Tags: c#, arrays, object, bubble-sort

C#, I'm trying to create an array in a class as an object. I want this program to run the method when I do a custom sort. I need to understand how to pass the value from the decimal array, already created from text to this object? I got something wrong somewhere. All I'm getting is the name of the form when I print out the array on the other side of front end of the form.

main form using call to class:  Sort sort = new Sort(rawArray);

```
using System;


namespace BbblSrtProj
{
    
    public class Sort
    {

        private decimal[] theArray;
        public Sort() { }
        public Sort (decimal[] sort)
        {
            this.theArray = sort;
            
        }
        public decimal[] TheArray
        {
            get
            {
                return theArray;
            }
            set 
            {
                theArray = value;
            }
        }

        //Sort Method: Bubble Sort
        public Array SortingMethod()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= TheArray.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                // Temp int variable to hold value in
                decimal temp;

                // Swap out adjacent value by order,
                // till completed.
                for (int j = 0; j < TheArray.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (TheArray[j] > TheArray[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = TheArray[j + 1];
                        TheArray[j + 1] = TheArray[j];
                        TheArray[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            return TheArray;
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You told us what you use to create the instance of Sort (`Sort sort = new Sort(rawArray);`) but what is your print statement in the calling code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Sort.cs 
//This Got it working

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

    namespace SortItProj
    {
    
        public class Sort
        {
            private decimal[] theArray;
    
            public Sort(decimal[] sort)
            {
                this.theArray = sort;
            }
    
            public decimal[] TheArray
            {
                get
                {
                    return theArray;
                }
                set
                {
                    theArray = value;
                }
        }

        public Array SortingMethod()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= TheArray.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                // Temp int variable to hold value in
                decimal temp;

                // Swap out adjacent value by order,
                // till completed.
                for (int j = 0; j < TheArray.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (TheArray[j] > TheArray[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = TheArray[j + 1];
                        TheArray[j + 1] = TheArray[j];
                        TheArray[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }    
            return TheArray;    
        }
    }

}

// SortItProj.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace SortItProj
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            decimal[] theArray = new decimal[55];

            int theArrayLength = theArray.Length;   
            decimal[] theArray2 = new decimal[theArrayLength];
            
            int i = 0;

            do
            {
                theArray[i] = (random.Next(1, 1000));
                i++;

            } while (i < theArray.Length);

            Array.Copy(theArray, theArray2, theArrayLength);

            Sort sort = new Sort(theArray);

            sort.SortingMethod();

            int j = 0;
            foreach (decimal number in theArray)
            {
                Console.Write(@$"{theArray2[j]} < RAW | SORTED > ");
                Console.WriteLine(number + "\n");
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a class with a decimal array as a property and a method that sorts the array for your homework? That's my best guess from what you wrote... If that's the case:

```
 public class SortingClass
{
    public decimal[] TheArray { get; set; }

    public void Sort()
    {
        // Do the sort
        
    }
}
```

Then you set the array and you call the method:

```
var sortingClass = new SortingClass();
sortingClass.TheArray = YourArray;
sortingClass.Sort();
```

But are you sure that's what the homework wants you to do? Because i don't see any reason for the array property in the class. Anyway, you should share more details about what you get wrong, if you want people to be able to help you.